# How to set the camera always to the center of the user's Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How can I solve that the camera always follow the user's Geolocation?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
trackuserlocationstart.trigger();
```

Sorry, but I'm really newbie in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as this:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(({ latitude, longitude }) => {
        map.panTo([longitude, latitude]);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast response. I got an error: `Geolocation.watchPosition is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, should have been navigator.geolocation.watchPosition.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition